# how to hide green pyramid of group objects handler

Tags: groups

when I handle group objects, green pyramid disturb me.
how can I hide these?

[image]
 https://gyazo.com/a8af6ff8d9810c374d0d4970e1bc3fe9

[image]

https://gyazo.com/d5fd3cfed539194daef6625d436c25f9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call "group objects" are in fact called *Group Instances*. They are objects using the *Dupligroups* feature to instance a group definition.

Any object can do that, but by default Group Instances are inserted in a scene as a *Empty* object type. Besides the group they are duplicating *Empty* objects can have a virtual representation in the 3D scene.

It can be one of several predefined shapes, and its size and settings can be controlled from the *Object Data* tab in the *Properties* editor.

What you are seeing are the arrows represeting these Empties. Either reduce the size of the empty display, or change it to something else that doesn't get in your way.

In the *Properties Window > Object Data> Empty* adjust the empty display settings.

Change it to either *Plain Axis* or something else that suits your need. Also reduce the *Size* property

[image: Blender Empty Display Settings]

Comment: thank you for answer. sorry, I didn't notice that this pyramid is empty object's . I learned new. thanks a lot !